# Keep pasted pre formatted code as it is -with tabs- in visual editor

Tags: tinymce, formatting, tabs, pre

I need a **manual code** to my functions php to **extend the visual editor from removing tabs** when pasting code blocks.

I tried this code, found at this site, but it does not work as *I want*. If I got:

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tiny_mce_before_init');
function tiny_mce_before_init($init) {
    $init['setup'] = "function(ed) {
        ed.onBeforeSetContent.add(function(ed, o) {
            if ( o.content.indexOf('<pre') != -1) {
                o.content = o.content.replace(/<pre[^>]*>[\\s\\S]+?<\\/pre>/g, function(a) {
                    return a.replace(/(\\r\\n|\\n)/g, '<br />');
                });
            }
        });
    }";
    return $init;
}
```

and paste into Visual, I got this:

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tiny_mce_before_init');
function tiny_mce_before_init($init) {
$init['setup'] = "function(ed) {
ed.onBeforeSetContent.add(function(ed, o) {
if ( o.content.indexOf('<pre') != -1) {
o.content = o.content.replace(/<pre[^>]*>[\\s\\S]+?<\\/pre>/g, function(a) {
return a.replace(/(\\r\\n|\\n)/g, '<br />');
});
}
});
}";
return $init;
}
```

I do understand that the TinyMCE settings does not intend to work with preserving tabs, as "it takes up space"...

I need a **manual paste & go** solution, not links to installing plugins that handles a lot of other stuff. Switching between the editors are not allowed to change anything either. Is it possible?

Thanks for reading and helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is, there is *no solution within the TinyMCE and Wordpress conversation* for this. But **There are diffrent approaches to work with coding material**.

I Shared this on an other discussion, but it might be a better context within your question.

**This solution** has been working for me many years, **and I love it**. This approach uses a "middle-hand" to serve correct pre-content and characters between the editors and `wpautop()` issues. It also **handles the entity char problems** switching between editors.

Just paste into functions.php

How to use: Create default pre-formatted textblock in the editor, like using the dropdown in the toolbar. Then inside the editor just Click on it -as you would do with images. A area appears to paste or edit, send it back. Just click on the pre block again to edit.

> It seems heavy, but its light. No modals API or whatever. But jQuery must be in "global scope" as it
>   **talks with tinyMCE API**. The dollarsign `$` can NOT be in use and **the
>   `jQuery` text clutter the code down**. Its mostly the *creation of
>   HTML elements* that takes space.

**How it works:** Pretty simple, *Without "touching" it -TinyMCE dont mess with it*. Its worth trying out!

```
/**
 * PRE Handler
 * Solves <pre> handle in Wordpress tinyMCE editor
 * TAB support
 * TAB support to TEXT editor
 * Simple cleanup with Undo
 * Push cleanup (experimental)
 * Moves empty code chunks to beginning
**/


function entex_tiny_mce_before_init(){
    add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', function($mceInit){
        $mceInit['setup'] = 'ua_TinyMCE_setup_callback';
        return $mceInit;
    });
    add_action('before_wp_tiny_mce', 'entex_TinyMCE_javascript');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'entex_tiny_mce_before_init');


function entex_TinyMCE_javascript() {

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'."\n";
    ?>

    var ua_tinyMCE_invoked = 0;

    function ua_TinyMCE_setup_callback(ed){

        if(ua_tinyMCE_invoked) return;
        ua_tinyMCE_invoked = 1;

        ed.on('init', function(e) {
            jQuery(ed.getBody()).on('click', 'pre', function() {
                ua_TinyMCE_edit_pre(ed, this);
                return false;
            });
        });
    }

    function ua_TinyMCE_helper_cleanBeginnings(str, find, replace){
        return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
    }

    function ua_TinyMCE_edit_pre(ed, obj) {
        var jQueryE = jQuery(obj); 
        var jQueryB = jQuery(ed.getBody());
        var content = jQuery('<textarea/>').html(jQueryE.html()).text();
        content = content.replace(/(<br>)/g, '');
        /* add whatever stuff to manipulate here */
        //content = content.replace(/   /g, '\t');
        var data = content;


        var jQueryL = jQuery('<div />').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'box-sizing': 'border-box',
            'background-color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85',
            'border': '3px solid #ccc',
            'padding': '10px',
            'z-index': '9992',
            'height': 'auto',
            'width': '80%',
            'left': '50%',
            'margin-left': '-40%',
            'top': '5%'
        });

        var jQueryT = jQuery('<textarea />').keydown(function(e){

            if ( e.which != 9 ) return;
            var start = this.selectionStart;
            var end = this.selectionEnd;
            this.value = this.value.substr( 0, start ) + "\t" + this.value.substr( end );
            this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;

        }).attr('wrap', 'soft').css({
            'height': '98%',
            'width': '88%',
            'min-height': '300px',
            'tab-size': '3',
            'font-family': 'courier new',
            'box-sizing': 'border-box'
        });

        jQuery('#wpcontent').css('position', 'relative').append(jQueryL);
        jQueryL.append(jQueryT);
        jQueryL.append(
            jQuery('<div />').css({
                'width': '10%',
                'height': '100%',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': '0px',
                'right': '10px',
                'padding-top': '10px',
                'box-sizing': 'border-box'
            }).append(
                jQuery('<a />').attr('title', 'Send to element').click(function(){

                    var encodedStr = jQueryT.val().replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
                        return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
                    });

                    jQueryE.html(encodedStr);
                    ed.focus();
                    jQueryL.remove();
                    return false;

                }).text('Send').addClass('button button-primary').css({
                    'display': 'block',
                    'width': '100%',
                    'margin-bottom': '5px',
                    'text-align': 'center',
                    'box-sizing': 'border-box'
                }), 

                jQuery('<a />').attr('title', 'Cleanup').click(function(){

                    var data = jQueryT.val();
                    var original = data;
                    data = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "\r\n");
                    var workspace = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '');

                    if(/^\s/.test(workspace)) {
                        var search_string = workspace.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
                        if(search_string){
                            var firstChar = search_string[0];
                            var remove = workspace.substr(0, workspace.indexOf(firstChar));
                            remove = "\r\n" + remove;
                            data = ua_TinyMCE_helper_cleanBeginnings(data, remove, "\r\n");
                        }
                        data = data.replace(/   /g, "\t");
                        data = data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
                    } else {
                        data = data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
                    }
                    if(data != original){
                        jQueryT.data('original', original);
                        if(!jQuery('#ua-TinyMCE-btt-undo').get(0)){
                        jQuery(this).after(
                            jQuery('<a />').attr('title', 'Undo').click(function(){
                                jQueryT.val(jQueryT.data('original'));
                                jQuery(this).remove();
                                return false;

                            }).text('Undo').addClass('button').css({
                                'display': 'block',
                                'width': '100%',
                                'margin-bottom': '5px',
                                'text-align': 'center',
                                'box-sizing': 'border-box'
                            }).attr('id', 'ua-TinyMCE-btt-undo')
                        );
                        }
                    }
                    data = data.replace(/   /g, "\t");
                    jQueryT.val(data);
                    return false;

                }).text('Cleanup').addClass('button').css({
                    'display': 'block',
                    'width': '100%',
                    'margin-bottom': '5px',
                    'text-align': 'center',
                    'box-sizing': 'border-box'
                }),

                jQuery('<a />').attr('title', 'Close').click(function(){

                    ed.focus();
                    jQueryL.remove();
                    return false;

                }).text('Close').addClass('button').css({
                    'display': 'block',
                    'width': '100%',
                    'margin-bottom': '5px',
                    'text-align': 'center',
                    'box-sizing': 'border-box'
                }),

                jQuery('<a />').attr('title', 'Remove all data').click(function(){

                    jQueryT.val('').focus();
                    return false;

                }).text('Delete').addClass('button').css({
                    'display': 'block',
                    'width': '100%',
                    'margin-bottom': '0px',
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'bottom': '10px',
                    'background-color': '#D54E21',
                    'color': '#fff',
                    'text-align': 'center',
                    'box-sizing': 'border-box'
                })
            )
        );
        jQueryT.val(content).focus();
        return false;
    }

    // WP EDITOR
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        if($('textarea#content').get(0)){
            $('textarea#content').on('keydown', function(e){
                if ( e.which != 9 ) return;
                var start = this.selectionStart;
                var end = this.selectionEnd;
                this.value = this.value.substr( 0, start ) + "\t" + this.value.substr( end );
                this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }).css('tab-size', '3');
        }
    });

    <?php
    echo '</script>'."\n";
}
```

This approach **is not a hack** or a corny preg match solution. It produces the same converastions as default API.

**The PUSH cleanup** works if you paste a code from a PHP class or whatever and the chunk or cutted out function you wanna present, has a lot of space or tabs "before". It calculates the space that occurs on the first existing line.

Makes this:

```
                    if(search_string){
                        var firstChar = search_string[0];
                        var remove = workspace.substr(0, workspace.indexOf(firstChar));
                        remove = "\r\n" + remove;
                        data = ua_TinyMCE_helper_cleanBeginnings(data, remove, "\r\n");
                    }
```

Into This:

```
if(search_string){
    var firstChar = search_string[0];
    var remove = workspace.substr(0, workspace.indexOf(firstChar));
    remove = "\r\n" + remove;
    data = ua_TinyMCE_helper_cleanBeginnings(data, remove, "\r\n");
}
```

**Note**, This is quite RAW, it can be customized very easy if you know jQuery. This function **also add TAB support** to the **Text editor**.

Tips: You should give your admin CSS tab-size: 3 to all your pre/ editor/ code-elements to match and sync the "visual" aspect.

Please use it, comment, And I will try to guide any improvements.

Comment: Works perfectly for my needs,  best approach ever. Thanks!